# Assignment involved with creating methods

Tags: java, arrays

first of all thank you for looking at my question. My assignment is pretty basic to most but I am an inexperienced programmer. Here is the description of the assignment:

Your objective is to write a class called Storage that can hold a collection of Strings. It must implement the following methods:

1. addItem(String s) - This method accepts a String parameter and returns a boolean value. The parameter reference is then stored internally in your choice of structure. The method returns true if the reference is successfully added.
2. getItems() - This method takes no parameters and returns an array containing all the Strings stored in the internal structure. The returned array must not contain any null elements.
3. isFull() - This method returns true if there is no internal storage available, otherwise false.
4. removeItem(String s) - This method accepts a String parameter and returns a boolean value. The method must search through the internal storage structure and remove the parameter reference (if present). The method returns true if the reference is successfully removed, otherwise false.

---

### I am completely stumped on most of these. I am using an array to store the data, but I am open to other suggestions. Thanks again.

Alright guys I made a few changes and I started some code, but it won't compile correctly. Based on the description of the methods can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

public class Storage {

```
//variables
private String[] list;
private int size = 10;
private int index = 0;

public boolean addItem(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (!list.equals(null)) {
            list[i] = s;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public String[] getItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(!list.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
        i++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    if (list.length > size) {
        System.out.println("The array is full");
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean removeItem(String s) {
    for (int i = index; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but you should realize that this is not a free code writing service.  Can you show us some code even if it be a work in progress?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what stumps you about writing these methods, most should be a one liner. If you are unclear on how to write a method I suggest you read some examples. e.g. the methods in ArrayList.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well I just started coding, I wondering how to use the proper if statements and for loops to complete this.

Comment: @Kory None of the method need `if` or `for` loops if you are using an ArrayList. If you are not using ArrayList or can't use it, I suggest you read the code for this class and use it for inspiration or just copy it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hmm, interesting. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Kory If you are using ArrayList each method can be implemented with just one line which starts `return ` all you need to do is to find the method which will do what you want for that method.  I suggest you read the javadoc for ArrayList to find the matching method.

Comment: Also @Kory, to fulfill your "isFull()" requirement, using ArrayList is not a good idea. ArrayLists will take as much space as the JVM lets it, creating a very large array. You should consider using a pre-initialized normal array of size 20 for example, that way the isFull() method can be practically incorporated. Arrays will also allow you to achieve every other requirement as well.

Answer (score 0):

`addItem(String s)`: The method should return a boolean value, since you are using an `ArrayList`, we can use `add(Object o)`, which returns a boolean.

```
public boolean addItem(String s) {
    return list.add(s); // I'm assuming that your instance variable is named list
}
```

`getItems()`: Use the method in the `ArrayList` class called `toArray()`, passing in an argument of the array type to cast to.

```
public String[] getItems() {
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

`isFull()`: Not exactly sure what your instructor was asking for here, as an `ArrayList` will automatically resize, but you could just add an instance variable to your class that contains a maximum size and then check against it like so...

```
public static final int SIZE = 10;
...
public boolean isFull() {
    return list.size() >= SIZE;
}
```

of course, this means adding code to check that the element you're adding doesn't breach capacity. I'll show this in the complete example below.

`removeItem(String s)`: The `remove()` method in `ArrayList` is overloaded to accept an object to remove. Likewise, this method also returns a boolean value.

```
public boolean removeValue(String s) {
    return list.remove(s); // Removes the first occurrence of the string
}
```

All in all, you should have something similar to the following...

```
public class Storage {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int SIZE = 10;

    public boolean addItem(String s) {
        if (isFull())
            return false;
        return list.add(s);
    }
    public String[] getItems() {
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
    public boolean isFull() {
        return list.size() >= SIZE;
    }
    public boolean removeValue(String s) {
        return list.remove(s); // Removes the first occurrence of the string
    }
}
```